# Finding not empty directories without subdirectories and specific sorting

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, fedora, find

I have a problem with my "homework" on studies.

I have to list all not empty directories from `/var` and `/usr`, which do not have subdirectories and their owner is not root user. Also, for each directory I have to show depth in directory tree, i-node number, size, permissions in human-readable and octal formats and absolute path to this directory, and sort it descending by i-node number.

Here is what I've currently done:

```
find /{us,va}r -type d \! -user root \! -empty -printf "%d %i %k %M %m %u %h/%f\n" | sort -rn
```

Now I just have to **eliminate directories with subdirectories** and **sort it by i-node number**.

So, here comes the questions:

1. How can I eliminate directories with subdirectories from this list?
2. How can I sort this list by i-node, which is in the second column?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Okay, I figured out something like this: `find /{us,va}r -links 2 -type d \! -user root \! -empty -printf "%d %i %k %M %m %u %h/%f\n" | sort -rnk 2`. Can anyone tell me if it's all right?

Comment: I'm curious; how does the 'links' help with finding directories that don't have subdirs?

Comment: @tink In case of directories, the number of subdirectories is stored as hard links count. By default, every directory _(except /)_ has two subdirectories: **'.'** and **'..'** (current directory and parent directory), so if I check if there's only 2 'links' for specified directory, I'll get only directories without _actual_ subdirectories.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please consider answering your question and accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was right. All I had to do was to add `-links 2` argument to `find`, so it will output directories with only 2 "hard links" *(which are **not** hard links - it's subdirectory counter and every directory has at least 2 subdirs - '.' and '..')* and `-k 2` to `sort`, so it will sort by second column.

Whole command looks like this:

```
find /{us,va}r -links 2 -type d \! -user root \! -empty -printf "%d %i %k %M %m %u %h/%f\n" | sort -rnk 2
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a python-based solution to your problem.

Save this snippet as e.g. x.py, and **chmod +x x.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
x=[]
for line in sys.stdin:
  x.append(line.rstrip())

y=x[:]
for i in x:
  mark=x.index(i)
  for j in y:
    if i.split()[6]  in j.split()[6]  and i != j:
      if i in y: y.remove(i)

for j in y:
  print j
```

Then pipe your find command (w/o the links bit) through it, and sort

```
find /{us,va}r -type d \! -user root \! -empty -printf "%d %i %k %M %m %u %h/%f\n" | x.py | sort -k2,2n
```